# How to do a gradient in the same contour of the object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gradient

I have a polygon in a irregular format and I want to fill it by using gradient. However, this gradient has to be in the same contour of the polygon. This means that, the gradient is not radial since this gradient will fill a "ball" in the center of the polygon. Further, it cannot be the linear since it does not the same contour of the polygon.

This is an example of the image that I want:

[image: An example]

I have tried it, but I really don't know how to reproduce this example. Please, I would like a solution in the illustrator or photoshop.

Comment: The last program I saw that did exactly what you want was Deluxe Paint III for the Commodore Amiga (contour gradient fill). It was great for making maps: you'd just draw a few random unconnected squiggles on your "land mass", contour fill with a brown and green gradient, and you'd automagically get something worthy of a National Geographic pull-out.

Comment: Where can I download this program?

Comment: Well, first you have to download a 25-year-old computer and operating system...

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution in Photoshop would be to use an Inner Glow with gradient and a large size:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator your best bet is a colour blend. See [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html) (Adobe Help) and see the second example (the cloud)

Comment: I would be more prone to upvote your answer if you provided further detail other than a link.  If that link were to ever go down your answer will be removed.  Link only answers are frowned on in SE and a majority of people downvote them.